# How to remove the welcome message on GNU Octave

Tags: octave, gnu

How can I remove the Welcome screen on GNU Octave because it is boring to look at it every time.

I don’t know where and how to write silent and quiet I tried many ways.

Comment: How do you usually launch octave? icon on the desktop? Where is the actual octave installation located? Usually you would just create a shortcut on your desktop, and you can pass options to the executable defined in there (right-click, properties, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
$octave --silent
```

For the furture, if you need to customize similar parameters (*e.g.* no gui etc), note that all of that can be seen with

```
$octave --help
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.I have to write this command on octave command window? Or on CMD??